# Proportions in python?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I am looking to have one preoperty follow another, but to be less in size. Example: speed is 1, proportion is 0.1; speed is 10... and so on. How would I achieve this? Thanks!

Code (not working):

```
import bge
from bge import logic

def property(cont):    
    own = cont.owner

    if 'Speed' in own and 'Recoil_Level' in own and 'Proportion_Size' in own:

        speed = own['Speed']
        level = own['Recoil_Level']
        size = own['Proportion_Size']

    else:
        print('No properties found in Weapon_Recoil_Level_Determiner')
        return

    level = speed / size
        print("recoil level: ", level)    

cont = logic.getCurrentController()      
property(cont)
```

Comment: Idk, maybe helping me with my question probably answer yours. I have dealt with similar things but not this sever as yours. A little more detail is fine or telling us what exactly is causing your problem would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always assign to the property itself not a copy of it :

```
import bge
from bge import logic

def property(cont):    
    own = cont.owner

    if 'Speed' in own and 'Recoil_Level' in own and 'Proportion_Size' in own:

        speed = own['Speed']
        level = own['Recoil_Level']
        size = own['Proportion_Size']

    else:
        print('No properties found in Weapon_Recoil_Level_Determiner')
        return

    own['Recoil_Level']= speed / size
        print("recoil level: ", own['Recoil_Level'])    

cont = logic.getCurrentController()      
property(cont)
```

`level` is just a copy ( not exactly but this how you should see it ) when you write  `level = speed / size` then `level` will change but  `own['Recoil_Level']` won't change

Comment: Yeah, I thought this was the issue but wasn't sure. I knew a smart soul would tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, it doesn't work. I thought it would, any thoughts?

Comment: @blackhole what errors you are getting ?

Comment: @Chebhou nothing appears.

Comment: @blackhole the script is running fine as expected can i have your setup ?

Comment: I have all 3 props and nothing appears in console and the prop doesnt change.

Comment: Got it, just fix the indent when it prints the level.